# How to downgrade my node.js from v8.9.3 to v6.11.2 on Mac

Tags: node.js

I am using macOS High Sierra V10.13.1. How to downgrade my node.js from v8.9.3 to v6.11.2

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: Use [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm)

Answer (score 0):

Use nvm https://github.com/creationix/nvm

There's a brew package for it as well